# How to add a button with code login into a Sharepoint 2010 List?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have imported a Sharepoint 2010 Custom List in InfoPath 2010 to redesign the form layout and published it.

I now want to add a button to the List which will do the following:

1. Open a different List in the UI;
2. Inherit some values from the source List into the new List;
3. On Save of the new List write a URL Link of itself back to the source List.

What would be the best approach for this?  I had hoped to use a button on form via InfoPath but the Developer tab is not available in a SharePoint List.

Trying to get my head round how this would work, and the best approach so any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do what you're trying to do using the SharePoint list form.  This is because these forms are limited to a single list and do not allow code.  If you added a second data connection (list), InfoPath won't allow you to publish it as a list form.

You can use the list form exported to Infopath as a starting point... however, you'll have to convert the form into a sandboxed solution or an Admin Approved form in order to publish it to SharePoint.

NOTE: The form will no longer be associated with that list... meaning, you won't see the from when you click View or Edit against the list it originally came from.

Hope this helps.